# Probability involving days of a week

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let's denote the $7$ days in a week as Monday=1, Tuesday=2, .... Sunday=7. Pick $N$ random people and the product of their corresponding birthdays' figures may or may not be divisible by $10$. Let's assume the probability of this product being divisible by $10$ for a given $N$ is $prob(N)$. What is the minimum value of $N$ for which $prob(N)>0.5$ and find this probability?

I tried a computations to begin with. I know that I would need a $2$ and a $5$ and the rest don't matter but I am not able to calculate the explicit expression and finding such an $N$ seems difficult to do as well. All thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The rest does matter, in particular $4$ or $6$ could replace $2$.

Comment: I think it is useful to rephrase by saying that every birthday contributes a $2$ (probability $\frac 37$), a $5$ (probability $\frac 17$) or neither (probability $\frac 37$).  It is not possible to contribute both a $2$ and a $5$.  Beyond that, the specific values are not important.

Comment: Extending lulu's idea to logarithms, if (as an example) $0.5 < p < 1$ and you want the smallest value of $n$ such that $p^n < 0.5$, take logarithms to give $n \log ~p < \log ~0.5.$

Comment: "I know that I would need a 2 and a 5"  You need an *even* and a $5$.  Or.. to go back to the weekday language, you need a Friday, and one of Tues,Thurs, or Saturday.

Comment: I think this is a good candidate for calculating compliment probabilities. You can have none of them a $5$ (which are $(\frac 67)^n$).  Or all of them odd ($(\frac 47)^n$) and inclusion/exclusion double counting the cases were all are odd and no fives are $(\frac 37)^n$ so probability *not* being divisible by $10$ is $\frac {6^n +4^n - 3^n}{7^n}$ and the probability of being divisible by $10$ is $1 - \frac {6^n +4^n - 3^n}{7^n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need at least a number in $\{2,4,6\}$ and a number in $\{5\}$ then you can count the probability to never obtain a number in the two sets or to obtain just one of them out of $n$ trials using the binomial distribution

$$P(\text{none}) =( \frac{3}{7})^n$$
$$P(\text{not both [case 1]}) =\sum_{k=1}^{n}{n \choose k} (\frac{3}{7})^n$$
$$P(\text{not both [case 2]}) =\sum_{k=1}^{n}{n \choose k} (\frac{1}{7})^k(\frac{3}{7})^{n-k}$$

So the probability is

$$p =1-( \frac{3}{7})^n - \sum_{k=1}^{n}{n \choose k} (\frac{3}{7})^n-\sum_{k=1}^{n}{n \choose k} (\frac{1}{7})^k(\frac{3}{7})^{n-k} \iff $$

$$p-(\frac37)^n-(\frac37)^n = 1-( \frac{3}{7})^n -  (\frac{3}{7}+\frac{3}{7})^n- (\frac{1}{7}+\frac{3}{7})^{n} \iff $$
$$p = 1 +(\frac37)^n -  (\frac{6}{7})^n- (\frac{4}{7})^{n} $$

You want $p>0.5 \iff (\frac{6}{7})^n+  (\frac{4}{7})^{n} -(\frac{3}{7})^n < 0.5 \iff 6^n+4^n-3^n < \frac12 \cdot 7^n$

The two functions (on the left and right side of the inequality) are increasing  at rates so that when $n$ is positive they have just one point of intersection and after that the rhs function is always greater than the other, therefore it's not difficult through experimentation to see that $n = 6$ is the required amount of people.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A_n$ be the event of at least one birthday of value $2, 4$, or $6$ in $n$ birthdays.

Let $B_n$ be the event of at least one birthday of value $5$ in $n$ birthdays.

We have $P(A_n^c)=\left(\frac{4}{7}\right)^n$,

and $P(B_n^c)=\left(\frac{6}{7}\right)^n$,

and $P(A_n^c \cap B_n^c)=\left(\frac{3}{7}\right)^n$.

We want the smallest $n$ for which $P(A_n\cap B_n)>0.5$.

Using DeMorgan and the Principle of inclusion-exclusion, we have

$P(A_n\cap B_n)=P((A_n^c\cup B_n^c)^c) =1-P(A_n^c)-P(B_n^c)+P(A_n^c\cap B_n^c)=1-\left(\frac{4}{7}\right)^n-\left(\frac{6}{7}\right)^n+\left(\frac{3}{7}\right)^n$

You should be able to finish it off from here.